Robotics Learning Path in Software, Simulation and Real Hardware
I would like to know learning path to expert in Robotics. Following shows what I learned already. Theories do not need to mention for this question.
Software and Coding:

ROS2
Solidworks
Blender
ROS2_Control
Nav2
MoveIt
MicroROS
AI (Reinforcement Learning)
MATLAB

Simulation Softwares

Gazebo Sim
Webots
PyBullet

Real Hardware

Arduino
Raspberry Pi
NVIDIA Devices

What else do I need to learn to do more complex application in real world implementation and simulation considering Software, Coding, Simulation and real hardware?

"learning path to exportin Robotics" and "Theories not need for now" in the same paragraph doesnt really make sense.

Ops. Sorry for that. I corrected it.

You are most likely overestimating your skills by a large margin, especially when looking at your other question from yesterday
It's a good idea to try minimal example projects:
An affordable real-world example is turtle-bot2
a more complex simulation example is universal robotic's Arm
Once the basic projects are running you can change them and solve new problems that come with the change: new sensors, new algorithms, new applications etc.
There is a lot more problems NOT solved than solved in robotics, which is exciting :)!
There exists an abundance of nice universities with a robotics program like ETH Robotics, who will benefit greatly from a motivated PhD-Student, too!
Regarding theory: there comes a point in any practical application where theory becomes very relevant again. Do not fully abandon it!

I am happy to learn more complex things. So while doing some projects or research with these, I would like to learn more softwares and real world implementation up to production level. I am plan to apply as a PhD student so need to learn.

I understand and respect that. Hence my best advice: get started on your own projects and get away from what I assume you did before: tutorials.While tutorials are meant to work, your own projects will provide you the opportunity to solve problems by yourself, without pre-defined solutions.

Thank you for the information. You mean these are all I need to learn and practice will shape it.

Yes. But it's not practicing what you already know: you will push the boundaries of what you know quickly, once you try to solve new problems. And by solving them, you will learn new skills.
